# Hardhat Deployment

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am trying to deploy a simple Token.sol script to a local network using hardhat though keep getting this error when running the script. I will post a photo of the error and then my migration script. Can anyone help here with what I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
await token.deployed();
```

instead of

```
await Token.deployed();
```

Hope this helps!